# Asking what to include - On topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I want to ask what to include in a first page text, would that be considered on topic or off topic? I noticed that asking what to write is off-topic, however I want to ask what to include, for example character name or such, in the text. Would it be considered on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can vary depending on the style of story you're telling, whether there's a prologue, whether it's part of a series... questions about openings are on-topic, but "what should I include?" might get closed as too broad or opinion-based.  For example, *Moby Dick* starts right off with "Call me Ismael" while in *The Time Machine* we never learn the name of the narrator.  So there's not a clear rule about names, but you could ask about when to introduce names, how/when to identify the POV character in a first-person narrative, etc.  Or you could ask what factors are most important if you're starting *in media res* and want a quick hook.  Or you could ask about conventions for the prologues of fantasy epics.  Bottom line, please try to be more specific about your context so your question is [good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).